# Cloth with pinning and collision is not wrapping body properly

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

Here are my modifiers settings
[image: physics settings]

If I did not turn on collision on body, cloth does not wrap all sides of the body:
[image: cloth no collision]

When I turn on the collision cloth did not fit on the pinning points

I am lost in it, can some body point out the issue?

[image: cloth with collision]

Updated:
As per suggestion added the solidify result is more or less same:

[image: cloth solidified]

**Pining Vertex group** and dress in edit mode showing edges

[image: the vertex group for pinning]

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, please take a look of updated question!

Comment: Yes, its on 2nd position and cloth is is the last item on the list

Comment: Can you show us how your cloth looks like in edit mode and where are the pinning points ? Can you try to scale up the cloth in X/Y plane at the waist ?

Comment: Please have a look of updates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64835/discussion-between-dominique-parisot-and-blender-for-you).